# display:footer is shown on the top of the table

Tags: displaytag

I paste my table code, using displaytag. 
My problem is that the [footer](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/tagreference.html#footer) is shown on the top of the table, and even using css I can not put it at the botton.

I am using a form around the table, and Spring web flow. Could it couse some conflicts?? If so, how could I fix it?
Any help would be really apreciated.

```
<form:form method="POST" id="tableForm">
    <display:table id="row" name="displayTagValueList" requestURI="overview?_eventId=tableAction">
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.item_name" value="Thread"/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.items_name" value="Threads"/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.group_size" value="5"/>
        <display:setProperty name="basic.msg.empty_list" value="No threads found."/>

        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.full" value='<span class="pagelinks"><a href="{1}">&lt;&lt;First</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{2}">&lt;Prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;{0}&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{3}">Next&gt;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{4}">Last&gt;&gt;</a></span>'/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.first" value='<span class="pagelinks">&lt;&lt;First&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;Prev&nbsp;&nbsp;{0}&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{3}">Next&gt;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{4}">Last&gt;&gt;</a></span>'/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.last" value='<span class="pagelinks"><a href="{1}">&lt;&lt;First</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{2}">&lt;Prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;{0}&nbsp;&nbsp;Next&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;Last&gt;&gt;</span>'/>


        <display:column title="">
            <form:checkbox path="chosenIds" value="${row.id}"/>
        </display:column>

        <display:column title="Some title" >
            <c:out value="${row.someValue}"/>
        </display:column>

        <display:footer>
            <div class="tableFooter" >
                <input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll(tableForm);'>  select all
                <input type="submit" name="_eventId_someTransitions" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </display:footer>
    </display:table>
    </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, display:footer tag must contain a table inside. `<div>` tags are not included in `tfoot`. So the solution was

```
<display:footer>
                <tr>
                    <td class="footerColumn"><input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll(tableForm);'>  select all
                    <td class="footerColumn"><input type="submit" name="_eventId_someTransitions" value="Send" /></td>
                    <td class="footerColumn"></td>
                    <td class="footerColumn"></td>
                    <td class="footerColumn"></td>
                    <td class="footerColumn"></td>
                    <td class="footerColumn"></td>
                    <td class="footerColumn"></td>
                    <td class="footerColumn"></td>
                    <td class="footerColumn"></td>
                <tr>
        </display:footer>
```

I find also quite anoying, that the styles are not taking if the class is declared in `<tr>` (the style is only a blackground color).

Besides, since in my table I have 10 columns, I have to declare 10 `<td>`, and all the column take the correspondent footer witdh. I have googled, but nothing found. Is there a way to play more independant with styles? The styles are just inherit from the table ones.